# (simple) variable and scope simulator

Tags: code-golf

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720579/implement-simple-interpreter-which-tells-us-current-value-of-a-variable-using-ja/14720954#14720954) closed question on stack overflow, what is the shortest way to stimulate scope for variables in an input.  For simplicity, `print` is replaced with `>`.

copying critical information from the linked source:

> `[` and `]` start and end a new scope.
>
> > Within scopes any changes to a variable outside of that scope is not permanent and is reverted when the scope has left, but the outer values are used to determine if a variable is undefined and its starting value.
>
> Input will always start with `[` and will end with matching `]`
> If its not defined then value should be `0`
> All input that is not a variable is a number with no decimal points. as in `10` or `582`
> `> a` means print the contents of `a`
> `a 10` assigns `10` to `a`
> `a b` assigns the contents of `b` to `a`
> Variables should be considered strings: `one 1` is valid syntax
> It is not required for the input to contain the print command `>`

**Note on scoring**:

```
You may chose how to input and output the "code", but it should be explained in the answer.
```

I answered this on the linked page in java, but I did not go for shortest code.
Comment any suggestions or questions, so I can improve my future posts.  Shortest code by character wins.  Good luck.

Comment: What is meant by "All input that is not a variable is an integer"? And why mention Java, which is actually quite different?

Comment: The interesting thing is, `>` is a special variable that outputs its value when assigned to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python 2, 165

```python
def f(v):
 while 1:
    s=raw_input().split()
    if'['in s:f(dict(v))
    elif']'in s:break
    elif'>'in s:print v.get(s[1],0)
    else:v[s[0]]=v.get(s[1],s[1])
raw_input()
f({})
```

Character count assumes tabs are used for the second level of indentation.

Comment: Nice solution. `c=b in v and v[b]or 0` can be replaced with `c=v.get(b,0)`.

Comment: Thanks. Great suggestion; using `.get` helps a lot.